# Typescript - Nested arrow function typing

Tags: node.js, typescript, arrow-functions

I have this code for deferring the execution of a function

```
export type DeferredFunction<T> = () => T | PromiseLike<T>;

export class Deferrable<T> {
  protected df: DeferredFunction<T>;

  constructor(df: DeferredFunction<T>) {
    this.df = df;
  }

  public async execute(): Promise<T> {
    return this.df();
  }
}

export const defer = <T>(df: DeferredFunction<T>): Deferrable<T> => new Deferrable<T>(df);
```

That works fine and I can run code like

```
await defer(() => someFunction('foo', 'bar')).execute();
```

but I what I want to do is type `DeferredFunction` in a way that I can specify the inner function's signature but I can't get it working.  In generic cases the above works but when I want to limit the arguments such that they are specific to a certain type of function I don't have that kind of control.

For clarity, I want to be able to type the inner function's inputs like (as an example)

```
export type InnerDeferredFunction<T> = (a: string, b: number, c: SomeObjectType) => T | PromiseLike<T>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could the `Parameters<..>` type help here? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst

Answer (score 0):

What "inner function" are you talking about?  Is it `someFunction`?  If so then the type of `DeferredFunction<T>` has no handle on it, since it's a function called by the *implementation* of `DeferredFunction<T>`.  There's no way in TypeScript to specify "a function whose implementation must call a function of type `(x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => string`".  Implementation details are not part of a function's call signature.

---

The only way I can imagine to begin to approach this would be for `DeferredFunction<T>` to accept as a parameter the inner function you want to call, along with the list of arguments to call it with.  This might not be what you're looking for, but it's the closest that the type system can represent.

Something like this:

```
export type InnerDeferredFunction<T, A extends any[]> = (...args: A) => T | PromiseLike<T>;
export type ZeroArgDeferredFunction<T> = InnerDeferredFunction<T, []>
```

Here I'm keeping `A` generic but you can specify it to some hardcoded list of arguments.   I've renamed your `DeferredFunction` to `ZeroArgDeferredFunction` to be explicit that it doesn't need arguments.

But now `Deferrable` needs to know about `T` *and* `A`:

```
export class Deferrable<T, A extends any[]> {
  protected df: ZeroArgDeferredFunction<T>;

  constructor(df: InnerDeferredFunction<T, A>, ...args: A) {
    this.df = () => df(...args);
  }

  public async execute(): Promise<T> {
    return this.df();
  }
}
```

And you can see that you have to construct one by passing it the inner function and its arguments, and the `ZeroArgDeferredFunction` is built inside the constructor and is not passed in.

There are different ways to define `defer()`.  It could be a thin wrapper around `new Deferrable` the way you had it, or you could imagine splitting it up so that the args come first:

```
export const defer = <A extends any[]>(...args: A) => <T>(
  df: InnerDeferredFunction<T, A>): Deferrable<T, A> => new Deferrable<T, A>(df, ...args);
```

And then you can test it like this:

```
function someFunction(x: string, y: string) {
  return (x + y).length;
}
function anotherFunction(x: number, y: number) {
  return (x * y).toFixed()
}

const deferFooBar = defer('foo', 'bar');
await deferFooBar(someFunction).execute(); // okay
await deferFooBar(anotherFunction); // error! string is not assignable to number
```

Once you call `deferFooBar('foo', 'bar')`, the returned value will only accept functions that can be safely called with the arguments `foo` and `'bar'`.  That means `someFunction` will be accepted and `anotherFunction` will be rejected.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7DwoBFgBmOUwAJgGICuGAxjAJYQYA8AKgDRwCCcoMwGUgGc4AQwyIA2gF0AfHAC8cABQA6daKgBzIQC5uASkXzWcAD5wAClAgBbekOAAZegGtgbWQG4AUKEiwCMioAFo4EFza+ERQJBTUdIwsrPJKmNh4hMRkVLQMTGycMrI+fuDQ8DQANqJCItHEogBGVR4c3Lwg-IIi4lJycADePnBwYDb8dGRwpAT6YTaRWg2xOQn5yd6lozRMQjBQlHTQyrP66TgrcbmJBe1cspzqqpo6+lxGw6OjMAAWDqpZooVEYFPJZmoNNohAZfKMAL7bMaUFr0GhiISIWidYA0Sj8ZQGfTWOwONryL7fEgwShQDAIf5CQEEQlwuDwuA+RFlAKVPbwUhZKDA5g8PgCYRiCTFSEvaHvUHyTzKEYzOboLCXIXXdZJQrcWREuBXZqtfUPYxwbAAd2N2tNbU4D1OBCeUJ0sNKBF1TDgQjswBuG2UIH0+yg9AwWk4iDDB0jWk+quptPpIbgAGo4IgDKpWlG-r5Ed68kkpRA-jgg0kQ-oMJRbE0cDG6w2m1Ak6MU3SVCA4AAqbO5mAQcj0EBkQlc0q7DD7GZC8gQCAAIU0wMFMWUAHICMvt5xt01NNvPaJraJ6ALF8u11BlP7bIGfRhc6BcfjgKy4AB6H8+c9L2vGIl1XTRlHECtfirF9YV-H9eFiaAAEI-XjKM4AcK0KwxIR6C0DAHQQCArTbHAgA)